# How do I import nodes into the Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-modules

I wants to import drupal nodes and blogs into facebook wall. Which module should I use for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to post on your Facebook page wall.

1. download [facebook php SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)
2. Implement [hook_node_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7)() hook, and use the following code.

   ```
   function YOUR_MODULE_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state)
   {
       $node_types = array("article", "blog");
       if(in_array($node->type, $node_types) && $form_state['clicked_button']['#id'] == "edit-submit")
       {
           $message = $form_state['values']['title'];
           $description = $form_state['values']['body'];
           $picture = $form['YOUR_IMAGE_FIELD']['und']['0']['#file']->uri;
           send_to_facebook($message, $description, $picture);
       }
   }

   function facebook_oauth_init($facebook_app_id, $facebook_app_secret, $cookie = false)
   {
       $facebook = new Facebook(array("appId" => $facebook_app_id, "secret" => $facebook_app_secret, "cookie" => $cookie));
       return $facebook;
   }

   function send_to_facebook($msg, $desc, $pic)
   {
       if(!class_exists('Facebook'))
           require_once('facebook/facebook.php');
       $fb_app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
       $fb_app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
       $fb_user_id = "THE_USER_ID_OF_THE_ADMIN_FOR_THIS_PAGE";
       $fb_page_id = "YOUR_PAGE_ID";
       $fb_access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
       $fb_reirect_uri = "";
       $access_token_2 = '';
       foreach($accounts as $acc)
       {
           if($fb_page_id == $acc['id'])
           {
               $access_token_2 = $acc['access_token'];
               break;
           }
       }

       $fb_post_array = array(
           'access_token'      => $access_token_2,
           'message'           => $msg,
           'picture'           => render(file_create_url($pic)),
           'description'       => $desc,
           'link'              => $fb_reirect_uri,
       );
       if($picture == NULL || $picture == "")
           unset($fb_post_array['picture']);

       $fb_now = $facebook->api("/" . $fb_page_id . "/feed", "post", $fb_post_array);
   }
   ```

That's all I did to post nodes to my facebook page.

Hope it works... Muhammad.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably interested on the [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) module.

> This set of modules and themes turns Drupal into a platform for developing Facebook Applications. This allows you to embed your content and features within facebook, or allow facebook users onto your site via Facebook Connect.
>
> With Drupal for Facebook, you can harness all the power of Drupal in you Facebook App. If you already have content in Drupal, you can expose it on Facebook.
>
> The Drupal for Facebook philosophy is that the functionality already built into Drupal should be used to create Facebook Applications. Where possible, we use Drupal's user management, permission schemes, blocks, views, etc. to implement the Facebook App. Experienced Drupal users will find it very straightforward to build a Facebook App. While Facebook developers new to Drupal may want to spend some time on Drupal.org learning best practices.
>
> Drupal for Facebook contains several sub-modules. Enable just those that you need. For example if you need Social Plugins, enable just fb.module. For Facebook Connect, enable fb_connect.module; Canvas Pages, fb_canvas.module; **wall posts and status updates, the fb_stream.module**; and so on...